# Stop/Start while loop with a boolean trigger - Python

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

Hi everyone out there!

I wrote a while loop to iterate over pages through an API.

What I'm trying to do is that the chunk of code STOPS iterating WHEN the Response 200 returns empty.

To be clearer:

*Page 1 = Data -> Append*

*Page 2 = Data -> Append*

*Page 3 = Data -> Append*

*Page 4 = NaN/Empty/Shape[0] == 0 -> **STOP ITERATING****

base_url and fecha are just variables I initialize before. it does not concern the issue here.

The response is a pandas.core.frame.DataFrame (I checked the df type). The response is response 200 and returns something like this:

[image]

I need to know if this is a so-called **good practice** or not.

```
dfs = []

keep_loop = True
page = 0

while keep_loop:
    URL = base_url + fecha + '&page=' + str(page)
    req = requests.get(URL,  headers=headers)
    df = pd.read_json(StringIO(req.text))
    dfs.append(df)
    page += 1
    if df.shape[0] == 0:
        keep_loop = False

df_final = pd.concat(dfs)
```

**Should I use a *boolean* to stop or initialize the *while loop*?**

**Any improvements or advices will be appreciated**

Comment: I guess, instead of having a variable, just do a `while True:` with a `break` in the if block.

Comment: thank you! I'll changed it to my code. Just wanted to be sure if it's reasonable what I was doing @TharunK